# Redirect to some other view after fetching information in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What if I want to redirect to some page after getting some information. Actually I need to have  a search box. Then I will get the entered information in some action and then want to redirect to any page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Action, add the following code:

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName",
                        "ControllerName",
                       new {
                           parameter1 = "something", 
                           parameter2 = "something else"
                           });
```